# Chrome dev tools truncates the form data while showing in request headers if it contains "="

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am not able to see the complete query parameter in chrome dev tools in query string contains "=".
It shows only till "=" and truncates there after.

Firebug shows it properly.
Please find the screenshots from firebug and chrome devtools for the ajax snippet shown here.

> ```
>     var qstring = "Hello=Hai";
>
>     $.ajax({
>         type: 'POST'
>         , url: "/cgi-bin/printenv.pl"
>         , data: "query=" + qstring
>         , dataType: 'xml'
>         , timeout: 10000
>         , success: function(jQuerySuccessData){
>                     }
>             });
> ```

[image: Firebug shows the complete query parameter]

[image: Chrome dev tools doesn't show the complete query parameter]

Is there any workaround available for this?

Thanks,
Naga Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to urlencode the query string as `=` is a reserved character. The easiest way to do this would be the `escape` function in javascript. Make sure you urldecode on the other side as well.

Comment: I don't have access to modify the code as am looking at the ajax requests of a production server. Yes "=" is a reserved character but Firebug handles it correctly. Is there any workaround in chrome dev tools like some configuration setting to handle this without modifying the code

Comment: I don't think there is. Why should they implement such a switch? Your Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you aren't supplying a string of that content-type, the debug tools are free to do whatever they want.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Ajax uses contentType :"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" by default.

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST'
                    , url: (isCLI == false ? this.execUiQuery : this.execCli)
                    , data: qstring
                    , dataType: 'xml'
                    , contentType: 'text/plain'
                    , timeout: 10000
                  });
```

I have overriden this setting and set as "text/plain" using javascript edit in chrome devtools and its showing the complete query string.